# The Object.Instantiate work differently after update version Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After installed *Unity 2017.3.0f3* (past vesion - *2017.2.0f3*) method Object.Instantiate not working properly.

```
public GameObject obj;

void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("Inst", 1f, 1.5f);
}

void Inst()
{

    //Instantiate(obj, new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(obj, new Vector3(Random.Range(-2.1f, 2.1f), 6f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

In this case I do a clone of *obj* but only with another *position*.

But *position* does not change. It is always the same.

I'm doing a 2D app.

*Game Window:*
[image]
Scene Window (front in 3D view):
[image]
Scene Window (in profile in 3D view):
[image]

Comment: Have you gone into 3D view and checked if it's moving towards the camera? Your scene for whatever reason could be rotated by 90 degrees. Also you could use just a 'Vector2' rather than a 'Vector3' for a 2D game

Comment: @AidanH, nothing is rotated (if I understood correctly what you are talking about). I tried to use a 'Vector2' but it did not help. And before the update everything worked (with a 'Vector3'.).

Comment: My other theory is that 2.1f is simply not enough of a range to make a visible difference. UI elements in unity are usually pretty large, so it indicates to me you might've had to scale your objects up to match the size of the UI. Try a bigger variance and see if there is a difference. Also a Vector2 won't make a difference - it is simply good practise. Also make sure that the script you have posted definitely runs.

Comment: I've tried to use `Random.Range(-2.1f,2.1f);` on my Unity 3.0f3, and it works fine. I think that @AidanH is right, you should log out the position of all your instantiated objects after you instantiate them, to check that the X position is indeed choosen randomly.

Comment: @AidanH, unfortunately no. Position (x) of clones is always the same. The code works good if I write its so:

GameObject tempObj = Instantiate(obj, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
tempObj.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-2.1f, 2.1f), 6f, 0f);

Comment: Could be a namespace issue with Random.  run console logs to see what values are being generated and try using Unity.Random

Comment: I transferred project to computer which has 2017.2.0f3 (past version) and I did insignificant changes there. As a result everything works again.

Why did it work !? I have no idea!

Then I transferred project to computer with 2017.3.0f3 (new version) and everything works again.

It is magic:)

Comment: I kept the project which reproduces issue, so if you have ideas then write.

Comment: @Josh Adams, I tried to set Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f) but the position has not changed